# CSS Tooltip with Span wont work

Tags: html, css

I read that you could make some easy CSS Tooltips with a Span, so I tried it, but it wont work for me and i have troubles figuring out why:

```
if($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $image = $obj->Image;
        $page  = $obj->Page;
        $name  = $obj->Name;
        if($image != null) {
            echo "<a href=" . $page . " target=_parent><img src=" . $image . " width=93 height=66><span class=info>test</span></img></a> ";
        }
    }
}
```

and the CSS:

```
  <style type="text/css">
    body,td,th {
        font-family: "Myriad Pro";
        font-size: 12px;
        background-color:#fcfcfc;;
    }
    a {
        border:none;
    }
    img {
        border:thin solid;
        border-color:CCC    
    }
    img:hover {
        opacity:0.5;    
    }
    span.info {
        display:none;   
    }
    img:hover span.info {
        display:block;position:absolute; width:200px; height:200px; 
    }
    </style>
```

My Problem is that the Span wont show at all.
Anybody some ideas how to fix this?

Comment: What browser are you using? Some older browsers don't support the pseudo-classes on parent selectors (i.e. `img:hover`)

Comment: Also, please provide rendered HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector you're looking for is this:

```
img:hover + span.info {
    display:block;position:absolute; width:200px; height:200px; 
}
```

The `+` is for adjacent elements.  Using a space is for descendant elements (and `span` is most definitely not a descendant of `img`).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that making it a hover event on the image tag will work as the span tag isn't a child of the image tag.

Image tags do not have a closing image tag like you have written in your code.

They can be closed by simply putting a slash at the end e.g.

```
<img src="" />
```

If you make it an event for the 'a' tag that should work e.g.

```
a:hover span.info {
    // your css here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things:

1. change "img:hover span.info" to "a:hover span.info", as the span is the child of the a tag, not the img tag
2. apply a positioning to the a tag (position:absolute will only be relative to the parent when the parent has position explicitly stated)

While the + selector mentioned above will indeed work on CSS3-enabled browsers, this will work on all browsers (IE8 and below).

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest anything inside an IMG tag as far as i'm aware (which is prob why it's not showing up) - do something like this:

CSS:

```
.tippedImage {
position: relative
}

.tippedImage span {
display: none;
position: absolute;
}

.tippedImage:hover span {
display: block
}
```

HTML:

```
<span class="tippedImage">
<img src="someimage.gif" />
<span class="tooltip">Tool tip text</span>
</span>
```